# Windows 8 store gridview design time doesn't work

Tags: windows, gridview, windows-runtime

I am currently learning Windows 8 Store development for a side project. I have a problem, because I couldn't get the GridView working with design time data.

I downloaded a proved example from http://irisclasson.com/2013/02/03/a-simple-design-time-data-example-with-windows-store-applications-for-beginners/designtimedata3_1/

but I could only see the real data. Even if I hardcode simple buttons in the GridView, I couldn't see them in the design view. Neither in Blend nor in Visual Studio:

Button 1
            Button 2
            Button 3
            Button 4
            Button 5

My Software configuration:

Windows 8.1
Visual Studio Premium 2012 Version 11.0.61030.00 Update 4 (most current)
Blend 2012

Comment: can we get some xaml or some code or an error message? Something.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with this code sample until I retargeted it to Windows 8.1 with VS2013. It seems like there is an issue with the GridView in design mode in both VS 2012 and VS 2013 when run on Windows 8.1.

As an experiment before retargeting, I added a ListBox with the same ItemsSource and it displayed fine in design mode.

I know this isn't an answer with a fix, but thought I'd mention it. I've been experiencing the same issue with EVERY Store 8 code sample I look at in design mode with a GridView. Any other control seems fine.

Edit: It's probably related to the ListView and GridView perf improvements in Windows 8.1 mentioned here [API changes for Windows 8.1](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dn263110.aspx). I'm guessing that you'd have to add some of the missing template in the XAML to make things visible in design mode. I'm going to try to figure it out.

Edit 2: I gave up trying to figure it out. Retarget to 8.1. We've all been recruited to push the adoption of 8.1 and Phone 8.

Comment: holy cow is this true, is this documented anywhere? I'm pulling my hair out here, and found your reply and am relieved to discover perhaps I'm not crazy after all!

Comment: I don't know if it's documented. Most of my Google searches about this exact issue come up empty. Lots of people with design-time exceptions causing gridviews to be empty, but not this issue. We seem to be the only 3 people who ran into it. :)

Comment: I posted in msdn here: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/941c641d-51f6-477e-a1eb-13a1fe156e14/design-time-data-not-visible-for-win80-apps-on-win-81?forum=winappswithcsharp and it looks like indeed this may be a bug. haven't heard anything since but I am curious to know if anyone knows a workaround; I cannot move to 8.1 until I update the 8.0 app, but it's difficult to do so when I'm moving around blind!

Answer (score 1):

so I ended up finding a fix for this, not sure if it's a real fix (meaning that it would work for anyone) but it certainly worked for me. I posted it in the [thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/941c641d-51f6-477e-a1eb-13a1fe156e14/design-time-data-not-visible-for-win80-apps-on-win-81?forum=winappswithcsharp) from the comment above but here it is again in case anyone else finds it useful:

I ended up fixing this and enabling the design-time data again by modifying the ItemsPanelTemplate of the GridView to be a VariableSizedWrapGrid. Simply adding this to the GridView:

```
<GridView.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
        <VariableSizedWrapGrid />
    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
</GridView.ItemsPanel>
```

seems to do the trick. Perhaps there is a bug in the regular WrapGrid when opening a Windows 8 app project on Windows 8.1? I'm sure the frequency of this is so low it's probably not worth doing anything about it, but hopefully someone who does search for this finds this helpful.

Comment: 2016, still an issue in Windows 10 apps :\ Thank you, that worked. God damn Silverlight.